# PostgreSQL executeBatch() slows down with time

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I have a program, which writes lines like 'name1 name2 score' into table with a `PreparedStatement` with upsert. So I execute this statement lots of time, adding it to batch. Batch size is 100, when it's full I do `.executeBatch()` and `con.commit()` (auto-commit is set to false in the beginning).

The problem is that on the first 10 minutes the program works, it writes data to database muck more faster, then after hours of working (the same job was done in 1-2 minutes at the start and in 10-20 after several hours). The profiler says that 94% of time it spends on `SocketInputStream.read()`:

[image]

So what can I do to prevent this awful slowdown?

Comment: Details? There's no "upsert" in PostgreSQL, so what statement *exactly* are you using? On what PostgreSQL and PgJDBC versions? Is the table empty before you begin this process, i.e. is it growing rapidly? If so, a slowdown is expected and normal.

Answer (score 1):

Put autoCommit false, and use prepared statements like the following:

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);  // The connection
PreparedStatement prepStmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO table (val1,val2) VALUES (?,?)");

for all values:
  prepStmt.setString(1,val1);
  prepStmt.setString(2,val2);
  prepStmt.addBatch();    

prepStmt.executeBatch(); 
conn.commit();
```